# How to get types to work in Deno when using import maps?

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments, deno

For some reason, types do not seem to work properly in Deno (version: 1.41.0) when using import maps.

This works:

```js
import Stripe from 'npm:stripe@14.12.0'
```

Screenshot from VS Code:
[image]

This doesn't work:

```js
import Stripe from '$stripe'
```

or

```js
// @deno-types="npm:@types/stripe"
import Stripe from '$stripe'
```

Screenshot from VS Code:
[image]

The import map in `deno.json`:

```json
  "imports": {
    "$stripe": "npm:stripe@14.12.0"
  }
```

VS Code's `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "deno.enablePaths": [
    "./"
  ],
  "deno.enable": true,
  "deno.unstable": true,
  "deno.config": "./deno.json",
  "deno.lint": true,
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resorted to using `deps.ts` (as described [here](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/tutorials/manage_dependencies)) instead of import maps, e.g.:

```js
// deps.ts
export { Stripe } from "npm:stripe@14.12.0";
```

and then importing any given dependency like this:

```js
// e.g. stripe.ts
import { Stripe } from "./deps.ts";
```

Everything works as expected when using this pattern and the overall DX is satisfactory.